# is there any difference between using jsoncol#>>'{key}' and (jsoncol#>'{key}')::text?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Option 1 - extracting json as text: `jsoncol#>>'{key}'`

Option 2 - casting json value as text: `(jsoncol#>'{key}')::text`

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some difference between their output: they handle `json` (and `jsonb`) `json 'null'` and string (f.ex. `json '"foo"'`) values differently:

```
select j #>> '{key}'        "j #>> '{key}'",
       (j #> '{key}')::text "(j #> '{key}')::text"
from (values (json '{"key":null}'),
                  ('{"key":true}'),
                  ('{"key":false}'),
                  ('{"key":"foo"}'),
                  ('{"key":12.34}'),
                  ('{"key":["array"]}'),
                  ('{"key":{"obj":"ect"}}')) v(j)
```

will produce:

```
| j #>> '{key}'   | (j #> '{key}')::text |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| NULL            | 'null'               | --> first is true SQL NULL
| 'true'          | 'true'               |
| 'false'         | 'false'              |
| 'foo'           | '"foo"'              | --> note the quotes
| '12.34'         | '12.34'              |
| '["array"]'     | '["array"]'          |
| '{"obj":"ect"}' | '{"obj":"ect"}'      |
```

The `(jsoncol #> '{key}')::text` variant always **casts** to text, which means it will display its JSON value's text representation, while `jsoncol #>> '{key}'` is defined to do some *conversion* to text.